# Why do I get a new line which is not there

Tags: c, cs50

I am learning C and when I write the following code and compile it there is one extra line printed.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    //set the int for height
    int height;
    //using do while loop to get the numbers between 1 to 8
    do
    {
        //using get_int helps get the positive number
        height = get_int("How High should be your Pyramid (Choose Between 1 - 8): ");
    }
    //this condition helps locking the numbers entered between 1 to 8
    while (height < 1 || height > 8);
    //for loop used for drawing # on screen at required hight entered by the user
    for (int i = 0; i <= height ; i++)
    {
        //BlankSpace int is used to find the number of blank spaces to move # to the right
        int BlankSpace = height - i;
        for (int k = 0; k < BlankSpace; k++)
        {
            //prints blank space to move right
            printf(" ");
        }
        //this will print # after the blank space
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        // move to new line
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

When I compile and run the file this is what it outputs:
`$ How High should be your Pyramid (Choose Between 1 - 8):`
When we provide anything from 1 to 8 it should look like this

```
$ How High should be your Pyramid (Choose Between 1 - 8): 8
       #
      ##
     ###
    ####
   #####
  ######
 #######
########
$
```

but what I get is the following:

```
$ How High should be your Pyramid (Choose Between 1 - 8): 8

       #
      ##
     ###
    ####
   #####
  ######
 #######
########
$
```

As you can see there is a line between

```
$ How High should be your Pyramid (Chose Between 1 - 8): 8

       #
```

Remember $ is the shell prompt.

Comment: Well, and what is your question then? Your program prints the line. Follow the code -  when the loop `for (int i = 0; i <= height ; i++)` first runs it's body, when `i = 0` - what will be printed?

Comment: At the first line does not execute `printf("#");` because `j` is not `< i`.

Comment: Try printing the value of `i` at the end of the line so you can see what's going on with `printf("%d\n",i)`, and then think about which values of `i` you actually wanted to print ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this loop

```
for (int i = 0; i <= height ; i++)
```

The first time it runs, `i` is `0`. So the `for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)` loop, which prints the `#`, runs zero times in that iteration. So no `#` will be printed on the first line, but the `printf("\n");` still happens, and the result is that an empty line has been printed.

One way to solve that would be by starting with `for (int i = 1;` instead of `0`.

Comment: yes it worked just by changing i t0 1 and still gor 8 lines printed

Answer (score -1):

What is definition of `get_int()`? I think it puts `'\n'` into stdout buffer.
If you remove `height = get_int("How High should be your Pyramid (Chose Between 1 - 8): ");` and assign `height = 8;` your "problem" disappears.

Comment: get_int() is from the header file cs50.h and we need to ask the question not a fixed 8. and @Blaze's answer worked for me

Comment: This is not really an answer — it is much more of a comment.  The speculation doesn't help.